# Files related to AIX HACMP Commands

Tags: aix

Are there any files which stores the output of the below HACMP command?

`cllsgrp`
`clshowres`

Comment: Guess you mean _Can I redirect the output of this command into a file?_ Yes, you can:  `yourcommand >filename`

Comment: No not the redirection. Any file which stores the output of these commands?

Comment: If you run these commands, you can redirect the output into any file. If you don't run these commands, you should ask someone else to do it. (`crontab` is an option.)

Comment: Do you want to know from where those commands get information?

Comment: Yes @romeo ninov

Comment: @ANaik, in such case please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://gibsonnet.net/blog/cgaix/html/Cluster%20Aware%20AIX.html) cluster configuration files are stored in shared disk (between nodes).

From [here](https://vceguide.com/where-is-a-cluster-aware-aix-cluster-configuration-data-stored/):

> The cluster repository disk is used as the central repository for the
> cluster configuration data. The cluster repository disk must be
> accessible from all nodes in the cluster and is a minimum of 10 GB in
> size. Given the importance of the cluster configuration data, the
> cluster repository disk should be backed up by a redundant and highly
> available storage configuration.